# Cakephp 2.0 View Cache Not Working

Tags: caching, cakephp-2.0

**Core.php** has the following

```
Configure::write('debug', 0); 
Configure::write('Cache.check', true); 
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
```

In the controller i tried the following

```
 var $cacheAction = true; 
var $cacheAction = array( 
                  'view/' => 5000 
               ) 
var $cacheAction = "1 hour";
```

The `view` folder inside app/tmp is always empty

Answer (score 0):

try removing the slash from 'view/', Cache Helper is not capable of routes its just doing string matching.